# Duda sobre constructor init en python

Tags: python, constructor

Me podrían aclarar si hay alguna restricción en cuanto a "buenas prácticas de programación" en lo siguiente:

¿Se puede usar en Python, estructuras condicionales o repetitivas dentro del constructor `__init__`?.

Algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El código, las trazas de error y demás, las compartimos **como texto** para que nadie tenga que replicar transcribiendo (nosotros tampoco te vamos a responder con imágenes para que tengas que transcribir código). Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta usando el enlace bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas.

Answer (score 1):

No hay razón para que sea "mala práctica" usar estructuras de control como `if` o bucles dentro de un constructor. De hecho, más bien diría que ese tipo de estructuras, sobre todo las condicionales, son típicamente usadas en los constructores.

Un caso de uso típico es precisamente el que ilustras en tu pregunta. Ya que el constructor tiene que *inicializar* el objeto recién creado asignando valores a sus atributos, y que éstos valores generalmente los recibe como parámetro, es habitual verificar que los parámetros recibidos estén en el rango esperado. En el ejemplo que planteas se ve que los campos `x` e `y` han de ser estrictamente positivos. En tu ejemplo, si uno de los parámetros se fuese negativo se cambiaría por cero.

Realmente no hay otra forma de hacer esto en el constructor, si no es mediante un condicional.

Otro caso de uso bastante habitual es tener constructores a los que se les pueda especificar diferente número de parámetros. Imagina por ejemplo que quieres crear una clase `Ejemplo` que tenga como atributos un contador y una lista, y que quieres hacer un constructor de modo que el objeto lo puedas crear con cualquiera de estas sintaxis:

```
d1 = Ejemplo(10, [3, 2, 1])  # Le pasamos todos los parámetros necesarios
d2 = Ejemplo(5)              # Omitimos la lista
d3 = Ejemplo()               # Omitimos ambos parámetros
```

Y queremos que cuando se omita la lista ésta se inicialice con una lista vacía, y si se omite el contador éste se inicialice con 0.

Ya que python no tiene *sobrecarga* (es decir, la posibilidad de especificar diferentes funciones `__init__()` que se diferencien en qué parámetros reciben), lo que habría que hacer sería asignar valores por defecto a los parámetros del constructor, por ejemplo así:

```
class Ejemplo:
   def __init__(self, contador=0, lista=[]):
      self.contador = contador
      self.lista = lista
```

El problema es que, si bien usar `0` como valor por defecto no plantea problemas, usar en cambio `[]` sí que plantea problemas bastante curiosos (y complejos de explicar aquí). Por lo que lo habitual cuando se desea el comportamiento descrito es especificar como valor por defecto para la lista el valor  `None`, para después verificar dentro de la función si el valor del parámetro es `None` para obrar en consecuencia.

Por tanto una implementación más correcta sería:

```
class Ejemplo:
  def __init__(self, contador=0, lista=None):
    self.contador = contador
    if lista is None:
       self.lista = []
    else:
       self.lista = lista
```

De nuevo esto no podría hacerse sin usar `if` dentro del constructor.

Los bucles son algo más raros, pero tampoco es difícil imaginar escenarios en los que serían útiles. Por ejemplo, el constructor debe inicializar una lista con valores comprendidos entre dos parámetros que recibe:

```
class Ejemplo:
   def __init__(self, inicio=0, fin=100):
     self.numeros = []
     for i in range(inicio, fin+1):
        self.numeros.append(i)
```

Si bien esto podría hacerse con una *list comprehension*, o más sencillo aún, usando directamente `list(range(inicio,fin))`, creo que sirve para ilustrar la idea general.